# routing between interfaces and nat (ip aliasing)

Tags: linux

I've 2 servers, both connect by switch0 (no vlan)
server1 has 2 NICS

```
eth0 --> switch0
ppp0 --> modem --> internet
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 1

192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.212 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

route:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.10.10.0      10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
151.7.202.72    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
172.16.212.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.116.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
```

server2 is:

```
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.252 netmask 255.255.255.0 --> switch0
```

with 3 lans, 3 NICS:

```
192.168.1.0/24 netmask 255.255.255.0 --> switch0
192.168.2.0/24 netmask 255.255.255.0 --> switch1
193.168.3.0/24 netmask 255.255.255.0 --> switch2
```

route:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use  Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.212      UGS         0   168553   bge0
10.10.10.0/24      10.10.10.1         UGS         0        0   tun0
10.10.10.1         link#12            UH          0        0   tun0
10.10.10.2         link#12            UHS         0        0    lo0
127.0.0.1          link#10            UH          0     1897    lo0
192.168.1.0/24     link#1             U           0    42375   bge0
192.168.1.252      link#1             UHS         0        4    lo0
192.168.2.0/24     link#7             U           0   117807    rl0
192.168.2.252      link#7             UHS         0        0    lo0
192.168.3.0/24     link#8             U           0   161828    rl1
192.168.3.252      link#8             UHS         0        0    lo0
```

I need create a routing from 192.168.1.0/24 to all other lans.

Should I using ip aliasing on server2?

Comment: You've left out some important information in order to properly answer this question.  The physical infrastructure and use case information is necessary.  If you have three separate physical NICs connected to a switch providing access to three different VLANs, you don't need IP aliasing.  If you have a port on a switch that presents three VLANs and the NIC is going to do tagging, that's also presents a different answer.  Aliasing allows you to assign IP addresses to a virtual interface.  It does not route packets.  You will need IP forwarding enabled to pass data from one net to the other.

Comment: Please post the routing tables of both servers, route -n, as well as the output of ifconfig on both servers. And, by the way, you do not necessarily need aliasing, you might get away with just routing, depending on your exact configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite easy.

On server 2: edit (as sudo) the file /etc/sysctl.conf, locate this line

```
  #net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and un-comment it,

```
  net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Save the file, issue the command:

```
  sudo sysctl -p
```

This is simply telling your kernel to allow packets to pass from one NIC to another.

Also, we need to configure NAT on it, so that return packets can be correctly routed via server2. Issue this:

```
  sudo iptables -t nat  -A POSTROUTING -o rl0 -j MASQUERADE
  sudo iptables -t nat  -A POSTROUTING -o rl1 -j MASQUERADE
```

This assumes your default iptables policies are all ACCEPT. If this is not correct, we shall have to punch a few more holes in your firewall.

Now to server 1. Issue the following commands:

```
  sudo route add -net 192.168.2.0/24 default gw 192.168.1.252
  sudo route add -net 192.168.3.0/24 default gw 192.168.1.252
```

These two commands are simply instructing your server1 that, should it find a packet destined to either 192.168.2.0/24 or 192.168.3.0/24, the packet should be routed to server2, which will take care of it.

You did not specify whether you wish clients on 192.168.2.0/24 or 192.168.3.0/24 to be able to access 192.168.1.0 through server2. If you do, then add

```
  sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o bge0 -j MASQUERADE
```

to your firewall.

Lastly, I very much hope the subnets 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 are **not** connected to Server1 through a different route, because this would imply that there are closed loops in your configuration, which requires some advanced instruments to deal with this properly.

Comment: MariusMatutiae: cheers! server2 is openbsd os. Its Already had equivalent firewall and forwarding rules. I solved following your advice: "route add -net" rules. Thanks for help! :-)